# Application not rendering all particles. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow, graphics2d

So I have a class project where we're  supposed to use MVC to refactor code that animates a system of particles using Java Swing. We utilize `Graphics2D` to accomplish this. I can get one particle to render, but am having issues rendering all of them. When read from an input file, the console reads that it added the 5 particles, but I only see one particle bouncing around on the screen.

The error I get when I try to iterate through the `ArrayList` of particles (`PSysModel`) is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:176)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2378)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
    at PaSkCode.PSysModel.<init>(PSysModel.java:22)
```

### Code

```
    public class PSysView {

    PSysModel Psystem;

    PSysView() {
    }

    // draw all particles in psm
    void draw(PSysModel psm, Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHints(new       RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTI     ALIAS_ON));
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    for(int i=1; i<=psm1.particleList.size();i++){
        PSysModel psm = psm1.particleList.get(i);
        g2d.fillOval(psm.px-psm.radius, psm.py-psm.radius, psm.radius*2, psm.radius*2);
        }
    }   

    // dump information on all particles in psm
    void dump(PSysModel psm, int lc) {
        System.out.println("Frame " + lc);
        System.out.println(psm.radius + " " + psm.px + " " + psm.py + " " + psm.velX + " " + psm.velY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you share the code for PSysModel as well with us?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @UweAllner Note that 1) An MCVE is preferred to random code snippets that the person who can't solve the question thinks might be relevant. 2) `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I created a separate class for the particle and then  used an arraylist of them to iterate through.

Comment: Glad you solved it. :) Now you might write an answer (below) or simply delete the question using the `delete` link below the question tags. And a tip: Add @UweAllner (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks buddy! Solution was to create a separate particle class and use an ArrayList <Particle> to iterate through in the model and views class.

Answer (score 0):

@AndrewThompson Thanks buddy! Solution was to create a separate particle class and use an ArrayList  to iterate through in the model and views class.